# Convergence interval for infinite product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

This is a simple one, but I do not manage to see it.

I have the infinite product $\prod_\limits{n=1}^\infty1+\frac{z}{n}$, with $z\in\mathbb{C}$. It's in the form as $\prod_\limits{n=1}^\infty1+u_n$, so it converges uniformly as $\sum_\limits{n=1}^\infty u_n$ converges uniformly.

So, for what $z$ does $u_n=-\frac{z}{n}$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, converges?

Comment: This is the harmonic series.

Comment: @Nitin, but do I have some $z\in\mathbb{C}$ for which the series converges?

Comment: The product diverges.

Comment: Converges only for $z=0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It converges only for $z=0$.  Note that

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac zn=z\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$

but,

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n>\int_1^\infty\frac1x\ dx\to\infty$$

So it has a radius of convergence $0$ and converges only at $z=0$ trivially.